# Fetched Result Controller delegate not called after swift 1.2 / xcode 6.3 update

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I just upgraded my project to swift 1.2. And after 5 or 6 consecutive 'Convert to latest Swift' action :), i was able to make it compiles.
Then i had lot's of my UI test failing. It was due to the fact that my 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate' was not called any more.

After (i might say) a very lucky attempt, i found that it as due to the fact that my delegate was not a NSObject. So i was able to fix it by subclassing NSObject or adding @obj.

Before:

```
class BasicFetchedResultControllerDelegate : NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

After:

```
class BasicFetchedResultControllerDelegate : NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

I don't think i saw something related to this in the change log. What is the changes that lead to that.
Did you notice other changes like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received this from Apple after i filled up a bug report:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>
> This is a behavior change in Swift 1.2: methods in non-Objective-C-derived classes will no longer be implicitly marked @objc even if they match an Objective-C protocol. You can explicitly mark the methods with the @objc attribute if you don't want to extend NSObject. This is described in the Xcode 6.3 release notes at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW3.

Comment: I have been bumping my head for days wondering why delegate methods are not called until I found this issue. Apple should mark it as compile error. Lesson learned: don't hesitate to make Swift classes inherit NSObject.

Comment: When I try to add NSObject in my class I get **Multiple inheritance from classes 'UITableViewController' and 'NSObject'**, whereas adding @objc() declaration doesn't make method behave as they should. What else could I try?

Comment: Another caveat, Swift will silently ignore delegate methods in generic classes, even if the class extends `NSObject` or uses `@objc`, e.g. `class F<T>: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` will fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data classes are still very much behaving like legacy Objective-C classes. As `NSFetchedResultsController` is a `@protocol` without any superclass, Swift needs the explicit `NSObject` declaration.

And you are right, there is nothing about that in the change logs.

Comment: I filled up a bug to apple, i believe that 'NSFecthedResultsControllerDelegate' should extend 'NSObjectProtocol'